# Spinner value into a ListPreference

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, preferences, listpreference

I'm trying to save a Spinner value into a ListPreference. I can't get it to work. I've tried to get this working for a long time now. Does anyone have a solution or can anyone point me in the right direction.

So this is what I have:

```
SharedPreferences preferences;

private static final String KEY_WEIGHT_PREFERENCE = "weightunit";
...

preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
...
```

This is the main part, both the Spinner and the ListPreference grab the same data from an array xml.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    Spinner weight = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightUnitSpinner);
    int selectedPosition = weight.getSelectedItemPosition();
            edit.putInt(KEY_WEIGHT_PREFERENCE, selectedPosition);
            edit.commit();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the `SpinnerValue` needs to be saved as a string in order to get recognized by the `ListPreference`.

Here's my final code:

```
private void updatePreferenceWeightValue() {

    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    Spinner weight = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightUnitSpinner);
    int selectedPosition = weight.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String weightValue = "";
    weightValue = Integer.toString(selectedPosition);
    edit.putString(KEY_WEIGHT_PREFERENCE, weightValue);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What isn't working?

There's a sample app called Spinner that contains a sample Spinner. It saves the state of the Spinner to saved preferences in onPause(), and restores it in onResume().

Comment: I tried the spinner example, and I'm able to save the spinner state to a preference. (same as above) But it doesn't load in the ListPreference. If I use the code I wrote above I get in the data/data/com.android.weight/shared_pref/ file the correct preference value (an int) but it wont load in the ListPreference.